# Read data from a text file and pass that data in a stored procedure input parameter using pl/sql scripts only

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper, plsql-package

I have a text file 'C:\file\Datafile.txt' which contains the below data.

```
1,Dixon,200
2,Sam,400
3,Peter,200
```

now I have a SP in oracle which accepts three input parameters (employeeid, employeename, salary).

I want to pass the values in that text file as an input parameter to this Stored Procedure one by one.

Kindly share any pl/sql script if possible to do this activity.

Comment: Is the file on the database server's file system?  Or the client?

Comment: The easiest way is to generate a PL/SQL block with call of that procedure as Excel formula for each row, then copy entire column and pass to SQL Developer, SQL*Plus or any other SQL client woth zero development effort. Or do the same with python/cmd/powershell or any other scripting language. It doesn't require any access to DB file system

Comment: I guess the txt file is in your laptop and not in the db server. Please, clarify that point. If you have an option to put this file in the db server, then it would be quite easy to do it. If not, I would recommend to use python to read the file and call the procedure using cx_Oracle.

Comment: File is in database server

Comment: Since the file in question is on the database server check out defining/using an [External Table](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sutil/oracle-external-tables-concepts.html#GUID-44323E01-7D72-45EC-915A-99E596769D9E).

Answer (score 0):

How to enable UTL_FILE package in oracle developer please let me now?

I am thinking of implementing the below solution.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE LoadFromFileData(p_FileDir IN VARCHAR2,p_FileName IN VARCHAR2)
AS
    v_FileHandle UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
    v NewLine VARCHAR2(100); -- Input line
    v_Column1 VARCHAR2(100);
    v_Column2 VARCHAR2(100);
    v_Column3 VARCHAR2(100);
    v_FirstConna NUMBER;
    v_SecondComma NUMBER;
    p_TotalInserted NUMBER;

BEGIN
    v_FileHandle := UTL_FILE.FOPEN(p_FileDir ,p_FileName, 'r');
    p_TotalInserted := 1;
    LOOP
    BEGIN
    UTL_FILE.GET_LINE(v_FileHandle, v NewLine);
    EXCEPTION   WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    EXIT;
    END;

    v_FirstComma := INSTR(v NewLine, ',', 1, 1);
    v_SecondComma := INSTR(v NewLine, ',', 1, 2);

    v_Column1 := SUBSTR(v NewLine, 1, v_FirstComma - 1);
    v_Column2 := SUBSTR(v RewLine, v_FirstConma + 1, v_SecondComma - v_FirstComma - 1);
    v_Column3 := SUBSTR(v Ne;Line, v_SecondConna + 1);
INSERT INTO LECTURER (ID, First_Name, Last_Nane, Major) VALUES (p_TotalInserted, TO_CHAR(v_Column1), TO_CHAR(v_Column2), TO_CHAR(v_Column3));
p_Totallnserted := p_TotalInserted + 1;
END LOOP;
UTL FILE.FCLOSE(v_FileHandle); COMMIT;
EXCEPTION
WHEN UTL FILE. INVALID OPERATION THEN 
UTL FIEE.FCLOSE(v FileHandle);
COMMIT;
EXCEPTION
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Uncessusful');
END LoadLecturerData;
```

Comment: Connect as sys(sys as sysdba);

    grant execute on utl_file to <username> or <public>;

Answer (score 0):

As you said that file is on the database server and you'd like to use `UTL_FILE`, then connect as a privileged user (such as `SYS`, if you don't have any other) and

- create a directory (Oracle object which points to a filesystem directory)
- grant read (and/or write) privileges on it to user(s) who will be using it

Why? Because `UTL_FILE` (as well as e.g. external tables feature, if you choose to use it) require the *directory*. SQL*Loader, on the other hand, doesn't - with it, file can reside on your local PC, not on the database server.

```
SQL> show user
USER is "SYS"
SQL> create directory ext_dir as 'c:\temp';

Directory created.

SQL> grant read, write on directory ext_dir to scott;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> grant execute on utl_file to scott;

Grant succeeded.
```

Now, connect as user which will be doing the job (`scott` in my case) and - using input file as you specified (`c:\temp\datafile.txt`) whose content is

```
1,Dixon,200
2,Sam,400
3,Peter,200
```

do the following:

```
SQL> create table test (id number, name varchar2(10), salary number);

Table created.

SQL> declare
  2    l_file  utl_file.file_type;
  3    l_line  varchar2(50);
  4  begin
  5    l_file := utl_file.fopen('EXT_DIR', 'datafile.txt', 'R');
  6
  7    loop
  8      begin
  9        utl_file.get_line(l_file, l_line);
 10
 11        insert into test (id, name, salary) values
 12          (substr(l_line, 1, instr(l_line, ',', 1, 1) - 1),
 13           substr(l_line, instr(l_line, ',', 1, 1) + 1,
 14                          instr(l_line, ',', 1, 2) - instr(l_line, ',', 1, 1) - 1),
 15           substr(l_line, instr(l_line, ',', 1, 2) + 1)
 16          );
 17      exception
 18        when no_data_found then exit;
 19      end;
 20    end loop;
 21
 22    utl_file.fclose(l_file);
 23  end;
 24  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Result:

```
SQL> select * from test;

        ID NAME           SALARY
---------- ---------- ----------
         1 Dixon             200
         2 Sam               400
         3 Peter             200

SQL>
```

Looks OK to me.